# Identify a book about scientist who used mescaline to see monsters

Tags: identification-request

As far as I can remember, a scientist in this book invented something based on mescaline and the result was that he - and others who followed this procedure - recognized that people are being exploited by energetic monster creatures.

- Mescaline has to be mixed with ether
- Monsters were otherwise invisible to people, but they were separate entities, that is not living inside human mind as suggested in "The Mind Parasites" by C. Wilson.

Comment: When did you read this and where? In what language? There must be something else you remember about the plot as well - names of the characters, maybe?

Comment: I cannot remember much more; quite sure that was English literature. Well, after these creatures actually noticed you notice them they'd kill you.

Comment: Colfer's [*The Supernaturalist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist) has blue energetic monster creatures that only very few can see (spoiler: for most of the book, appear to exploit humans, but are actually helping them). There *was* a scientist who tried to make others able to see them by causing threats to their safety, but IIRC there was nothing there about mescaline.

Comment: will read it as well :-) for now cannot tell if it was it, rather not.

Comment: @J.Doe: Because you responded to my comment, and because someone upvoted it, I posted it as a proper answer. For future reference, if you want someone to see a response to a comment, include their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. (I didn't get a notification for your response; I just happened upon it.) I hope you find the book you're looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like "The Mind Parasites" by Colin Wilson.

- The protagonist is a scientist
- He learns that the human minds are controlled by bodiless parasites which can in theory be seen but distract the host's attention when he tries to focus on them
- He used mescaline to focus his attention on the parasites and eventually get rid of them

Comment: Now I have read and enjoyed "The Ming Parasites" very much, but I am also quite sure that despite some similarities it is not the one I am looking for. (e.g. the parasites where not inside the mind)

Answer (score 3):

Colfer's *[The Supernaturalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist)* has blue "energetic monster creatures" called "Parasites" that only very few humans can see. These monsters appear to exploit humans, sucking out their life force.

> It is revealed toward the end of the book that they are actually helping humans, by alleviating the pain of the dying.

There was a scientist who tried to make others able to see them by causing threats to their safety, but, if I remember correctly, there was nothing in the book about mescaline.

Comment: *The Supernaturalist* has no main characters who are scientist-inventors. I'd be surprised if someone remembered Faustino or Myishi without remembering the gang of kids that the story is mostly about.